# Countable noun for someone who doesn't identify with an assigned culture

Tags: single-word-requests

I know this topic has been popping up here and there. And a good thread was once here [What do you call someone without a nationality?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/355948/251772)

But I'd like to elaborate.

How do you call someone who exists outside and independently from their parents', fatherland's/motherland's, assigned culture? That means, they don't identify nor share anything from the culture assigned at birth, by birthplace, and their family.

Someone who has built and is building their own culture as they explore and experience whilst taking what makes sense to them. Be it physically living in a certain place, travelling, reading, watching, talking, etc.

I know one word that describes it quite well but I can't seem to find a countable noun that could be used to describe a person of these attributes. The term is "transcultural" / "transculture". But calling one a transcturalist seems to be rather odd. Another one is a bit ambiguous, vague, and lengthy - "global citizen", "world citizen".

These are the quotes about transculturalism I found on various websites:

Reinventing of the new common culture.
Such reinvention of a new common culture is in turn based on the meeting and intermingling of the different peoples and cultures.

Transculturalism is a new form of humanism based on the idea of relinquishing the strong traditional identities and cultures which […] were [the] products of imperialistic empires [...] interspersed with dogmatic religious values.

Transculturalism opposes the singular traditional cultures that evolved from the nation-state.

Transculturalism is based on the breaking down of boundaries, and is contrary to multiculturalism because in the latter most experiences that have shown [reinforces] boundaries based on past cultural heritages.

Transculturalism is rooted in the pursuit to define shared interests and common values across cultural and national borders.

Transculturalism can be tested by means of thinking "outside the box of one's motherland" and by "seeing many sides of every question without abandoning conviction, and allowing for a chameleon sense of self without losing one's cultural center".

Transculturalism is characterised by cultural fluidity and the dynamics of cultural change. Whether by conflict, necessity, revolution or the slow progress of interaction, different groups share their stories, symbols, values, meanings and experiences. This process of sharing and perpetual 'beaching' releases the solidity and stability of culture, creating the condition for transfer and transition. More than simple 'multiculturalism', which seeks to solidify difference as ontology, 'transculturalism' acknowledges the uneven interspersion of Difference and Sameness. It allows human individuals groups to adapt and adopt new discourses, values, ideas and knowledge systems. It acknowledges that culture is always in a state of flux, and always seeking new terrains of knowing and being

Transculturalism is the mobilization of the definition of culture through the expression and deployment of new forms of cultural politics

Transculturalism emphasizes on the problematics of contemporary culture in terms of relationships, meaning-making, and power formation; and the transitory nature of culture as well as its power to transform.

Transculturalism is interested in dissonance, tension, and instability as it is with the stabilizing effects of social conjunction, communalism, and organization; and in the destabilizing effects of non-meaning or meaning atrophy. It is interested in the disintegration of groups, cultures, and power.

Transculturalism seeks to illuminate the various gradients of culture and the ways in which social groups create and distribute their meanings; and the ways in which social groups interact and experience tension.

Transculturalism looks toward the ways in which language wars are historically shaped and conducted.

Transculturalism does not seek to privilege the semiotic over the material conditions of life, nor vice versa.

Transculturalism accepts that language and materiality continually interact within an unstable locus of specific historical conditions.

Transculturalism locates relationships of power in terms of language and history.

Transculturalism is deeply suspicious of itself and of all utterances. Its claim to knowledge is always redoubtable, self-reflexive, and self-critical.

Transculturalism can never eschew the force of its own precepts and the dynamic that is culture.

Transculturalism never sides with one moral perspective over another but endeavors to examine them without ruling out moral relativism or meta-ethical confluence.

Sources:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transculturalism
And others (will try to find)

Comment: This is a very interesting concept. You've done a good job of searching for and providing a wide range of perspectives on transculturalism. It would be interesting to see the sources of the quotes, and might help guide others in seeking other terms to describe it. it is not easy to come up with an appropriate word to answer your question. Are you more interested in someone whose outlook spans many cultures, or someone who has created his/her own culture?

Comment: I looked at the thread you mention at the beginning of your question. Someone there suggested _cosmopolite_. I think that comes very close to what you're talking about.

Answer (score -1):

The title of the post does not ask quite the same question as the body, to which I offer, from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/maverick),

> **maverick**
>   NOUN
>   an unorthodox or independent-minded person
>
> *They want independent minds, mavericks and free thinkers.*
>
> *Far from being a deep-dyed traditionalist, he is a maverick, a valuable eccentric, who uses his influence to stimulate rather than stifle debate.*
>
> *A maverick, and an individual, he's running on instinct, fuelled by experience and making the right decisions.*

The word can have a negative undertone – to those whose orthodox views have been transcended.

(In AmE dialect it also means an unbranded calf.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please help to make my thread better. In terms of post-body relation.

Comment: Well, "someone without an assigned culture or race" is rather different from one who has outgrown the restrictions of their cultural upbringing, and I don't see how one could "unassign" their race, because that is a genetic matter, although they could choose to be unspecific about that in their milieu, as being irrelevant.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I'll make it more clear. Unassigned race in a sense that choose not to identify as any. I'm mixed with many "races" and I look like one "race" so neither I'm perceived as mixed nor as the "race" that I dislike less. I simply don't believe in the concept of race as determining factor of... basically anything.